# convert object to type generic - automapper static extension

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I'm trying to convert my AutoMapper code to be more fluent-api like, e.g.
existing code:

```
Model.Foo target = Mapper.Map<Contract.Foo, Model.Foo>(source);
```

What I'd like the code to look like is this

```
Model.Foo target = source.ConvertTo<Model.Foo>();
```

I started writing my extension method, but I can't seem to get this to work.

```
public static class AutoMapperConverterExtension
{
    public static T ConvertTo<T>(this string source) where T : new()
    {
        Type sourceType = Type.GetType(source); 
        if (IsMapExists<sourceType, T>()) // complains here! cannot resolve 'sourceType'. If I use inline, won't compile.
        {
            return Mapper.Map<T>(source);    
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException("type not supported for conversion");
    }

    public static bool IsMapExists<TSource, TDestination>()
    {
        return (AutoMapper.Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>() != null);
    }        
}
```

Comment: And what problems are you having with your implementation?

Comment: *complains here* about what?

Comment: updated the post -- basically, won't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are over-complicating things, and you might be able to get away with:

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object source)
{
    return Mapper.Map<T>(source);
}
```

That said, you can't use generics as you are attempting to do in the code code as posted.  `sourceType` is a runtime variable, and cannot be used for a generic type argument, which is determined at compile time.  In this particular case, AutoMapper provides a non-generic version of `FindTypeMapFor()` that you can use.

You also cannot assume that `source` is going to be a string parameter.  You probably want an `object`.

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object source) where T : new()
{
    Type sourceType = Type.GetType(source); 
    if (IsMapExists(sourceType, typeof(T)))
    {
        return Mapper.Map<T>(source);
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException("type not supported for conversion");
}

public static bool IsMapExists(Type source, Type destination)
{
    return (AutoMapper.Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(source, destination) != null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The line throwing the error needs to change to use reflection when calling the generic function.

```
var method = typeof(AutoMapperConverterExtension).GetMethod("IsMapExists");
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(sourceType, typeof(T));

bool exists = Convert.ToBoolean(generic.Invoke(null, null));

if (exists) 
{
    return Mapper.Map<T>(source);    
}
```

[How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Comment: thank you, I learned something new, but I marked the other answer as correct as it better solves the problem I was facing.